# Minimal temperature setting for hot water heater to prevent legionella

Tags: water-heater, safety, energy-efficiency

I own a small apartment which I rent out to tenants. The apartment has an electric hot water heater with 80 liters. I now realized that my tenant reduced the temperature setting to only 32 degrees Celsius. (*it's summer where I live*)

I have read the following advice to prevent legionella.

-Always keep the water at 60° Celsius

-Heat the water once a week to at least 60° Celsius.

Obviously to save electricity I would prefer the second solution, However is this safe if the water is only at 32° for the remaining time?

Can heating the water twice to 60° and keeping it at 32° Celsius be assumed to be safe?

Comment: Boiler? do you mean hot water heater ?  https://www.cdc.gov/legionella/wmp/index.html

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yes!

Comment: re-heating water is not like re-freezing food.  each heating kills all the legionella.

Comment: @Jasen Yes but is it enough to heat the water to 60 °C once a week and keep it at 30-34° C the rest of the week?

Comment: 32°C is only 90°F - that's not even hot enough for washing dishes or taking a shower, to say nothing of killing any bacteria. If your tenants are too hot, they can take a cooling shower by _not_ using as much hot water. In general it's not safe to have the hot water that cold.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, but if you heat it once or twice a week to 60°C to kill the bacteria? If you like cold showers 32°C is enough, and the shower is right next to the water heater

Comment: _Even if_ heating it 2x/week is sufficient (and I don't know), how long does it have to be that hot? Can you count on the tenants to do it, or are you stopping by? This sounds like _way_ to many "ifs" to me, and too many possibilities for something to go wrong and you to get sued. °C indicates you're not in the USA, but we're working hard to export our "sue first, ask questions later" mentality to the whole world (you're welcome), and to me, it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: "we're working hard to export our "sue first, ask questions later" mentality to the whole world (you're welcome)"..Made my day..You are obviously right..

Comment: if it's done the exact same time every week (eg on a 7 day timer)  it will spend some time at 60 degrees and thus the time it spends cool will be less than 7 days  satisfying every possible definition of "at least once a week"

Answer (score 2):

[OSHA recommends](https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/legionnairesdisease/control_prevention.html)  a water heater temperature of 140 Fahrenheit  (*60 degrees Celsius*)  to prevent legionella growth.

The [CDC  has information](https://www.cdc.gov/legionella/wmp/index.html) that is helpful.

As a landlord you will want to prevent scalding and legal issues associated with scalding,  so  anti-scald devises would be recommended.

Doing your own research would be the proper way to educate yourself as to  guidelines and pertinent info  to address your concerns.

Also, ask your local health Dept for any public resources/info available in your area.

Comment: yeah having a variable water temperature could be a risk to the tennant.

Comment: But if you have a water tank at 60 C (140 F) I would say you had better have a thermostatic mixing valve or valves between the water heater and the shower to insure that the hot water coming out of the shower cannot exceed 49 C (120 F). If you do not have thermostatic mixing, then there is a scald risk if the water in the tank is above 50 C. Water at 50 C would be too hot for showering, but I suppose it would not cause immediate scalding like 60 C water would. I think typically tankless water heaters are set for 50 C output.

Comment: At 60 C it takers about a 5 seconds to cause burns, so yeah not immediate, and not a health risk to able bodied people who can be expected to escape the hazard naturally